# How To Properly Transfer References from One Arraylist to Another

Tags: java, arraylist

Im making a card fighting game and seem to be having a problem with arraylists
I have 1 arraylist which has all the available cards in the game, 
and another playlist which has the cards that user chooses to use.

The 2nd arraylist starts of empty, and when the user starts picking cards from the first arraylist, that card gets transferred into the 2nd playlist.

The problem is that, if the user chooses 2 of the same cards, then what happens to one card also happens to the other. So lets say user chooses card called "Super man" twice. And when 1 Super man's health drops the other one also drops.

My code looks like this for adding a card to choosen cards:

```
//choosenCards is the arraylist of cards that the user chooses
//cards is the arraylist of available cards
choosenCards.add(cards.get(index));
```

Comment: Your problem results from the fact that you only have one object for the "Super man" card, but more than one reference. Changes made through any reference will affect the single object, so you'll see all changes through all the references. You need more objects if you intend to have a card chosen twice.

Answer (score 2):

"Adding" a card like that actually just adds a reference that points to the original object. What you want is probably a "deep copy" (so you get two independent versions from the original).

Use `choosenCards.add((Class of the card object) cards.get(index).clone());`

The reason for `(Class of the card object)` is that `Object.clone()` returns an `Object`, which then needs to be cast to the correct type.

Comment: To accomplish this, the Card class needs to implement Cloneable interface and override Object.clone (which is protected) with a public method

Comment: How would I make a cloneable interface ?

Comment: @HassanAhmed add `implements Cloneable` to the class definition (and then you have to implement the `clone()` function I think). It should basically just initialize a new instance and set the appropriate values like the original. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transfer from `cards` to `choosenCards` you need to use [remove(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)).

```
choosenCards.add(cards.remove(index));
```

Note that after removing a card from cards the maximum available index is one less before.

You code instead add a card to `choosenCard`, but doesn't remove from `cards`.

Comment: I don't want to transfer. I still want the cards in the arraylist "cards" to stay there. I just need to fill up the choosenCards arraylist with specific cards for the cards arraylist

Comment: The problem is that probably you need to really transfer cards. Perhaps you need to add different copies of the same card if it is possible to have duplicates.